# How to use external urls for product images in Magento

Tags: magento

It appears you cannot load product images as external urls eg http://somewhere.com/products/product1.png thus bypassing the local media storage. I'm astonished that Magento does not support this (if it's correct).

Other than paying for a Magento plugin, what is the easiest way of ensuring that my image/smallimage/thumbnailimage fields correspond to the full urls that i load in the products.csv ?

Am using Magento 1.6.2.0

[edited to avoid sounding snarky]

Comment: Your question is phrased quite snarkily and seems to imply that development in Java (or Java developers themselves) somehow author classes and frameworks which lack code duplication and have unencumbered module APIs with canonical access for each property. Having taught several Java developers learning PHP and Magento, I'm sure that snark must not be your intent, as these former students pointed out *plenty* of capacity to create and examples of dodgy Java work.

Comment: I think you mean dodgy PHP work ? (unless you were teaching them Java while they were learning PHP and Magento, otherwise how did you see their Java ?). Yes it's easy to produce bad code in any language but expectations for big name open source projects are going to be higher (again, whatever the language).

Comment: "capacity to create - and examples of - dodgy Java work"

Comment: why were they creating dodgy java work while being taught PHP and Magento ?

Comment: They weren't. They pointed out that, like PHP, Java development is replete with examples of bad apps and poor craftsmanship.

Comment: why were they pointing out lots of examples of bad java while being taught PHP and Magento ?

Comment: They were responding to others' criticisms of PHP as the problem and Magento as evidence of the problems of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definitive answer, just a note of what i've done in the meantime:

Edit app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
In the file you'll find two instances of "img src", for each of those two src attributes I changed the value to:

```
src="<?php echo $_product->getSmallImage() ?>"
```

Edit app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
Search for id="image"
changed the src attribute to be:

```
src="'.$_product->getImage().'"
```

In my product csv i'm loading the image and small_image values accordingly (as being the entire url including protocol and host etc).

There are undoubtedly other places where this similar changes should be made (eg wishlist pages etc), but at the moment thats the proper images showing in the grid data and product details view which is good enough for me for now.

Full answer still sought.

Comment: In the end we added up copying the images locally and using the magmi image processor plugin to load them (I was going to just "wget url" for each product image, but it turned out we could transfer them all by ftp from the original server)

Answer (score 1):

Add a new attribute for storing external image url for product. Then use the attribute to get the image.

Suppose the attribute name is ext_url user the below code to get the image.

```
<img src="<?php echo $product->getExtUrl();  ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think we must have posted simultaneously because I also just edited some of the php as a stopgap solution, however the question was more targeted at finding out how to get the result without altering any of the php templates or making one change somewhere (because otherwise I would need to find everywhere in the system where each type of image was used and change them all)